# Avoid Time Machine popup from disk

Tags: macos, mac, time-machine

I want to deliver a software pre-installed on a hard-drive.

When plugging the drive for the first time on a Mac, I get the Time Machine popup.

I wonder if there is any tricks to do on the external disk itself to avoid this annoying popup.

What are the conditions for the Time Machine popup to be shown ?

Comment: What is it you are *actually* trying to achieve? "pre-installed" has no real meaning on a Mac. Apps are delivered by simple .dmg or for items that need to be installed at system level, by pkg. Any Mac with no existing Time Machine drive associated will, as far as I know, ask if the new drive should become associated as a Time Machine drive. This is not controllable by you as 'app delivery' but by the Mac's user.

Comment: I only want to know if there is a way to create a disk which will not prompt the time machine popup when plugged. You say there isn't, ok I accept this answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered that MacOS put a file called `._.com.apple.timemachine.donotpresent` on the root folder of the drive after refusing to use it as a TimeMachine.

It's a tiny binary file, with a few information in it but I cannot really reverse engineer it.

I have not seen the popup since the file is here.

This is the closest answer I can do to my question and I will edit it if I found more on the subject.